# Get class property depending on generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

Lets say i have this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    public IMyInterface<Foo> Foos {get; set;}
    public IMyInterface<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}
```

I want to have a method like this one

```
MyClass.Interfaces<T>()
```

Which will return MyClass.Foos or MyClass.Bars Depending on T value.
How i do that?
It's very similar on how EF works.

Comment: What should be returned in case of several `IMyInterface<Foo>` properties? Do you want to use this with another interface types? How this should behave in case of multiple type arguments (e.g. `ISomeAnotherInterface<TParam1, TParam2>`)? Should this be reusable? What EF functional do you mean?

Comment: This question isn't related to Entity Framework. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IMyInterface<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public IMyInterface<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public IMyInterface<T> Interfaces<T>()
    {
        var property = GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("IMyInterface")
                        &&
                        x.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Contains(typeof(T)))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (property != null)
            return (IMyInterface<T>)property.GetValue(this);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for. What if the interface is not generic? Let's say something like: {class foo: MyInterface} {class My class { public foo foos {get; set;} } }

Comment: At this case you should exclude `.GenericTypeArguments.Contains(typeof(T))` condition or look for `foos` property.

Answer (score 1):

It requires some plumbing and casting, but you could do that with a dictionary:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> {
}
public class Foo { }
public class Bar { }

public class MyClass {

    Dictionary<Type, object> myInterfaces = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public IMyInterface<Foo> Foos {
        get { return (IMyInterface<Foo>)myInterfaces[typeof(Foo)]; }
        set { myInterfaces[typeof(Foo)] = value; }
    }
    public IMyInterface<Bar> Bars {
        get { return (IMyInterface<Bar>)myInterfaces[typeof(Bar)]; }
        set { myInterfaces[typeof(Bar)] = value; }
    }

    public IMyInterface<T> Interfaces<T>() {
        return (IMyInterface<T>)myInterfaces[typeof(T)];
    }

}
```

Comment: What, if there will be dozens of such properties. Obviously, it will be very tedious to copy paste corresponding snippet.